# How to create method to display average based on code listed

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sdasfs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double SelectNumber = 0;
        int a = 0;


        do {
            try {
                String UserInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
                SelectNumber = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value must be an integer!");
            }
        } while (SelectNumber < 1);

        double Numbers[] = new double[(int) SelectNumber];

        for (a = 0; a < Numbers.length; a++) {
            String EnterNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number.");
            Numbers[a] = Double.parseDouble(EnterNumber);


        }
    }


        //Create method in order to calculate calcavgnow


    public static double showAvg(String n){
        return JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getTotal(Numbers) + " divided by " + Numbers.length + " is " + getAvg(Numbers));
    }

    public static double getAvg(double numbers[]){
        return getTotal(numbers)/numbers.length;
   }

   public static double getTotal(double numbers[]){
      double total = 0;
      for(double i:numbers)
          total +=i;
      return total;
   }

}
```

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is nce main receives the average back from the "average method" it should call another method to display the average.  This is what I want it to show:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getTotal(Numbers) + " divided by " + Numbers.length + " is " + getAvg(Numbers));
```

However, I am receiving an error and am currently stuck.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `I am receiving an error`. That's really bad. Can you please tell us, which error ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Not everybody speaks a fluent English. Be leniant

Comment: @Kabulan0lak I mean, OP needs to show the error to us. We don't know which  error OP countered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to code are mentioned in comments. Main change - make Numbers[] global

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    // make Numbers global
    public static double Numbers[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double SelectNumber = 0;
        int a = 0;

        do {
            try {
                String UserInput = JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Enter the amount of numbers you would like to average");
                SelectNumber = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane
                        .showMessageDialog(null, "Value must be an integer!");
            }
        } while (SelectNumber < 1);

        Numbers = new double[(int) SelectNumber];

        for (a = 0; a < Numbers.length; a++) {
            String EnterNumber = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Please enter a number.");
            Numbers[a] = Double.parseDouble(EnterNumber);

        }

        // just checking
        showAvg("");

    }

    // Create method in order to calculate calcavgnow

    // changed to void as function is void function
    public static void showAvg(String n) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getTotal(Numbers) + " divided by "
                + Numbers.length + " is " + getAvg(Numbers));
    }

    public static double getAvg(double numbers[]) {
        return getTotal(numbers) / numbers.length;
    }

    public static double getTotal(double numbers[]) {
        double total = 0;
        for (double i : numbers)
            total += i;
        return total;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**problem:**

```
 double Numbers[] = new double[(int) SelectNumber];
```

the scope of that array is only in the main method nothing else so by the time you used this:

```
return JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getTotal(Numbers) + " divided by " + Numbers.length + " is " + getAvg(Numbers));
```

`Numbers field` wont be found, that it is not a valid variable in the class `sdasfs`

**solution:**

set `Numbers` as the `global field` of your `sdasfs` class so you can access it/ or static if you want to access it from main without creating object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring `double Numbers[] = new double[(int) SelectNumber];` inside main, you should declare it as a static class variable. Above the function declaration for `public static void main` you should put `static double Numbers[];` so that any code in the class can access it. Then, at the function in `main` where you currently declare and instantiate `Numbers`, just make it instantiation only instead: `Numbers[] = new double[(int) SelectNumber];`

Alternatively, modify your `showAvg` function declaration to take the array as a parameter:
`public static void showAvg (double[] Numbers)` and remove the `return` keyword in showAvg. As far as I can see, you aren't using the `String n` parameter it currently takes, either...